# Export to pdf in ActiveAdmin. (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, activeadmin

I want to add  export to PDFs in my app in ActiveAdmin, but i don't know how. Have anybody Experience? How i can add simple csv/pdf output in Show for any Order, but not for all?

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Order do

  actions  :index, :show, :edit, :destroy
  index download_links: [:pdf, :xml] #only for all Orders, but bot pdf
  show download_links: [:pdf, :xml] #This not work for any Order

  index do
   column :id
   column :name
   column :address
   column :email
   column :pay_type
   column :created_at
   actions
  end

  show do
    panel "Order Information" do
       table_for(order.line_items) do |t|
         t.column("Product") {|item| auto_link item.product }
         t.column("Quantity")   {|item|  item.quantity }
         t.column("Price")   {|item| number_to_currency item.product.price * item.quantity }
       end
     end

     panel "User Information" do
       table_for(order) do |t|
         column "Name", :name
         column "Address", :address
         column "Email", :email
         column "Pay Type", :pay_type
         column "Created:",  :created_at
       end
     end
  end

  sidebar "Total price",:only => :show  do
    number_to_currency order.line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this, with the help of prawn gem https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

I defined one module as `PdfReport`, and I want to generate pdf for `Profile`.
pdf_report.rb

```
require 'open-uri'
  module PdfReport
  def autogenerate_report
    p = self
    pdf_file_name = p.transliterate("Report-#{p.name}-#{Date.today.to_s}")
    pdf_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{pdf_file_name}.pdf"
    Prawn::Document.generate(pdf_file_path, :top_margin => 0, :bottom_margin => 0) do
      font "Helvetica"
      repeat :all do
      # header
      bounding_box [bounds.left, bounds.top], :width => bounds.width, :height => 100 do
      move_down(5)
```

So I am including that

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Shared::AttachmentHelper
  include PdfReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Prawn gem is awesome. But i have added simple javascript code to my ActiveAdmin Application in Order.rb.Now I can  save and prind pdf with Browser. I know, its not a Ruby solution, but its work and its save in pdf what i need - products in order and customer name and so on. `javascript:if(window.print)window.print()`
Also simply temporary solution, before i find something simple to integrate to ActiveAdmin.